Is a Windows 10 bootrec.exe forward compatible with Windows 11?
I'm helping someone fix some boot issues with Windows. So far we've narrowed at least one problem to the BCD, for which the usual fix is to execute bootrec /rebuildbcd after deleting the existing BCD (example question that is somewhat related).
However, this doesn't work in this case, with bootrec /rebuildbcd continuing to be unable to find any Windows installations with which to populate a boot menu.
As it turns out, we're using Windows 10 installation media (version 1703, released back in 2016) to fix a Windows 11 install (version 1742, Windows 11 first being released in 2021).
I have conflicting intuitions about whether I would expect this operation to work across versions:

Maybe Windows 11 has a unique way to boot, and bootrec explicitly does not try to be forward compatible.
Why would Windows 11 be making breaking changes to the boot system?

The obvious next step is to use Windows 11 installation media to fix the Windows 11 install, but I'm wondering if there were any explicitly breaking changes to the way Windows 11 boots?
(There are some rumblings about BCD changes breaking dual booting, but it's not very specific, and I wasn't able to find more concrete information.)

In my experience bootrec is like crap/bs under many circumstances. Never got why it is often mentioned by those tutorial sites or "tutorial people". Unless your BCD has very special configuration or complex multiboot records whatsoever, you can literally ditch the whole ESP / "boot partiton" and reconstruct one with bcdboot. (Either reformat it or create a new one if you want leave the old one untouched and that there is space for you to do so.) For fixing MBR/VBR (if you are still with legacy booting), there's bootsect that is way less obscure.

(But of course if you create a new ESP / boot partition, you will either need to choose the correct ESP/WBM on your UEFI boot menu, or change the "active" partition for the case of MBR disk / legacy booting. Some UEFI firmware does not support multiple ESPs per disk too, like the Phoenix ones, at least the "locked" / simplified variants.)

So everything is forward compatible ... until it isn't. Basically the same rules as DLLs. As long as none of the exposed signatures are modified, (types, methods, and parameters) the library remains compatible with code compiled to use a prior version. in your case, you are working with a configuration generator, so if the application that parses that configuration changes. perhaps to enable new features or improve the expression of the configuration,  a configuration generated by a late-version generator may, quite reasonably, not work correctly.

What error are you trying to solve, perhaps we can help you solve that problem, instead of answering the question you asked?

For posterity, the actual error involved was about an improperly built BCD "The Boot Configuration Data file doesn't contain valid information for an operating system". File: \BCD, Error Code 0x0000098. Looking at the actual contents of the BCD didn't highlight anything wrong, which is partly why I leapt to a potential break in compatibility.

This was brute force resolved by re-installing Windows; unfortunately time did not allow for further debugging. Before doing so, we did verify that using Windows 11 installation media did not fix the BCD issues, so at least one error was not around Windows 10 vs 11 compatibility. We couldn't root cause the error and/or demonstrate Windows 10 did work, so I'm not posting this as an answer.
